# How to call a function inside a StatefulWidget from another StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter

I come here asking for help to understand if it is possible to put one or several functions outside a `StatefulWidget` followig an example that I found in the internet.

The following code example is working and it is to connect over Wifi to a ESP32 Microcontroller.
Inside the `StatefulWidget` there are some functions like for example `void channelconnect()`, `void initState()` etc. My question is how I can put these functions outside the `StatefulWidget` in another Widget. Is it possible to seperate the Logic from the UI?

```
void main() => runApp(
      const GetMaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
    );

final key = GlobalKey<WebSocketLed1State>();

//----------------------------------------------------------------
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: WebSocketLed1(),
    );
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class WebSocketLed1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebSocketLed1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => WebSocketLed1State();
}

class WebSocketLed1State extends State<WebSocketLed1> {
  late bool ledstatus; //boolean value to track LED status, if its ON or OFF
  late IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  late bool connected; //boolean value to track if WebSocket is connected
  var val = -255.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("LED - ON/OFF NodeMCU"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent),
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //inner widget alignment to center
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: connected
                      ? const Text("WEBSOCKET: CONNECTED")
                      : const Text("DISCONNECTED")),
              Container(
                  child: ledstatus
                      ? const Text("LED IS: ON")
                      : const Text("LED IS: OFF")),
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: TextButton(
                      //button to start scanning
                      onPressed: () {
                        //on button press
                        if (ledstatus) {
                          //if ledstatus is true, then turn off the led
                          //if led is on, turn off
                          sendcmd("poweroff");
                          ledstatus = false;
                        } else {
                          //if ledstatus is false, then turn on the led
                          //if led is off, turn on
                          sendcmd("poweron");
                          ledstatus = true;
                        }
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child: ledstatus
                          ? const Text("TURN LED OFF")
                          : const Text("TURN LED ON"))),
              SizedBox(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Brightness: '
                            '${((255 - val.toInt().abs()) / 255 * 100).toInt()}%',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 24.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                          RotatedBox(
                            quarterTurns: 3,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 200,
                              child: Slider.adaptive(
                                value: val,
                                min: -255,
                                max: 0,
                                onChanged: sendMessage,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ledstatus = false; //initially leadstatus is off so its FALSE
    connected = false; //initially connection status is "NO" so its FALSE

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      channelconnect(); //connect to WebSocket wth NodeMCU
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  void channelconnect() {
    //function to connect
    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
          "ws://192.168.204.65:81"); //channel IP : Port
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(message);
          setState(() {
            if (message == "connected") {
              connected = true; //message is "connected" from NodeMCU
            } else if (message == "poweron:success") {
              ledstatus = true;
            } else if (message == "poweroff:success") {
              ledstatus = false;
            }
          });
        },
        onDone: () {
          //if WebSocket is disconnected
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print("Web socket is closed");
          setState(() {
            connected = false;
          });
        },
        onError: (error) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(error.toString());
        },
      );
    } catch (_) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("error on connecting to websocket.");
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendcmd(String cmd) async {
    if (connected == true) {
      if (ledstatus == false && cmd != "poweron" && cmd != "poweroff") {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print("Send the valid command");
      } else {
        channel.sink.add(cmd); //sending Command to NodeMCU
      }
    } else {
      channelconnect();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("Websocket is not connected.");
    }
  }

  void sendMessage(double v) {
    try {
      setState(() {
        val = v.roundToDouble();
      });
      channel.sink.add('clear\n');
      channel.sink.add('${val.toInt().abs()}\n');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont have a solution, I can just point you in some directions: For a clean architecture, there are packages like Provider, BloC or RiverPod. Note: The list is by no means exhaustive and strongly influenced by my own opinion/expierience.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was taken a lock on Provider, Bloc and RiverPod and also Getx. There is a lot that i have to learn,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to define a class and define your function in it and then call functions you want any where you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Abraams. After reading a little more about State Management in Flutter i stucked with the Getx package. I tried to understand how it works and i implemented it. Right now i have the logic out from the UI but because of the missing setState my Slider is static. On the screen it does not move but in the backgroud he is working.

Comment: It is my pleasure friend                                                                                                              Handling state with Getx package is so easy and all you have to do is using Get.arguments to get whatever you want from another screen

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @最白目, thanks @Abraams gtr for your help.
Also thanks @Tomerikoo for making a review on my inicial question. :)

Like i told, it was the first time for me, here asking for help and i am not familiar with stackoverflow.

After searching on the internet for some info for my quetion i could find a solution.
It can be that it is not the best way to make it, but it is working. For sure there is a better way to make it.
I will continuo working on it. Of course if there is somebody with a better method i would appreciate another point of view.
Flutter and Dart are completely new Land for me.
Follow my approach for my inicial question.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const GetMaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder(
      init: MessageController(),
      builder: (GetxController controller) {
        return const WebSocketLed();
      },
    );
  }
}

class WebSocketLed extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebSocketLed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Slider'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Brightness1(),
              Slider1(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Slider1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Slider1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messageController = Get.put(MessageController());
    return SizedBox(
        child: GetBuilder<SliderController>(
      init: SliderController(),
      builder: (ctrl) => SizedBox(
        child: Slider(
            value: ctrl.quality,
            min: 0,
            max: 255,
            divisions: 255,
            label: ctrl.quality.round().toString(),
            onChanged: (double value) {
              ctrl.setQuality(value);
            },
            onChangeEnd: (messageController.sendMessage),
            onChangeStart: (messageController.sendMessage)),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Brightness1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Brightness1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        child: GetBuilder<SliderController>(
            init: SliderController(),
            builder: (ctrl) => SizedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    ctrl.quality.round().toString(),
                  ),
                )));
  }
}

class MessageController extends GetxController {
  late IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  late bool connected;
  var val = 255.0;

  void sendMessage(double v) {
    try {
      val = v.roundToDouble();
      channel.sink.add('clear\n');
      channel.sink.add('${val.toInt().abs()}\n');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
          "ws://192.168.75.5:81"); //channel IP : Port
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(message);
        },
        onDone: () {
          //if WebSocket is disconnected
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print("Web socket is closed");
        },
        onError: (error) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(error.toString());
        },
      );
    } catch (_) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("error on connecting to websocket.");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
class SliderController extends GetxController {
  static SliderController get to => Get.find();

  double quality = 255;

  void setQuality(double quality) {
    this.quality = quality;
    update();
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).